# NuxtJS Auth error with property doesn't exist

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

I've just installed *@nuxtjs/auth* on my project.

I get `Property '$auth' does not exist on type 'AuthLoginPage'` class.

## Method login on login class page

```
this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
        data: {
          username: 'your_username',
          password: 'your_password'
        }
      });
```

## My nuxt.config.ts

```
modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
  ],
...
auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3001/users/login',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'token'
          },
          logout: {
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3001/users/logout',
            method: 'post'
          },
          user: {
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3001/users/me',
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: 'user'
          }
        },
        // tokenRequired: true,
        // tokenType: 'bearer'
      }
    }
```

It's impossible for me to use NuxtJS Auth.

Have you got an idea please?

Comment: did u add it to nuxt config? if yes - show your config

Comment: @Aldarund Yes, I added the nuxt.config.ts auth config plugin.

Comment: did you add it into modules section of nuxt config, you showed only part of your nuxt config...? And where are u calling it? in what method?

Comment: @Aldarund Sorry, I forgot to add entirely the config :) I updated the first message. Have you got an idea?

Comment: create a repro on codesandbox, hard to say without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem caused when you add Typescript to vueJs project with NuxtJs.

The solution of this warn of types, posted in official web of define types DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

1. You need to create a file in your root project types/index.d.ts and add this code

```js
    <pre>
    // Type definitions for @nuxtjs/auth 4.8
    // Project: https://auth.nuxtjs.org
    // Definitions by: Ruskin Constant <https://github.com/jonnyparris>
    //                Daniel Leal <https://github.com/danielgek>
    //                Nick Bolles <https://github.com/NickBolles>
    // Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
    // TypeScript Version: 3.1

    import Vue, { ComponentOptions } from 'vue';

    export interface Storage {
      setUniversal(key: string, value: any, isJson?: boolean): string;
      getUniversal(key: string, isJson?: boolean): any;
          syncUniversal(key: string, defaultValue: any, isJson?: boolean): any;
      // Local State
      setState(key: string, val: any): string;
      getState(key: string): string;
      watchState(key: string, handler: (newValue: any) => void): any;
      // Cookies
      setCookie(key: string, val: any, options?: object): any;
      getCookie(key: string, isJson?: boolean): any;
      // Local Storage
      setLocalStorage(key: string, val: any, isJson?: boolean): any;
      getLocalStorage(key: string, isJson?: boolean): any;
    }

    export interface Auth<T = any> {
      ctx: any;
      $state: any;
      $storage: Storage;
      user: Partial<T>;
      loggedIn: boolean;
      loginWith(strategyName: string, ...args: any): Promise<never>;
      login(...args: any): Promise<never>;
      logout(): Promise<never>;
      fetchUser(): Promise<never>;
      fetchUserOnce(): Promise<never>;
      hasScope(scopeName: string): boolean;
      setToken(strategyName: string, token?: string): string;
      getToken(strategyName: string): string;
      syncToken(strategyName: string): string;
      onError(handler: (error: Error, name: string, endpoint: any) => void): any;
      setUser(user?: Partial<T>): any;
      reset(): Promise<never>;
      redirect(name: string): any;
    }

    declare module 'vue/types/options' {
      interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
        auth?: boolean | string;
      }
    }

    declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
      interface Vue {
        $auth: Auth;
      }
    }

    </pre>
```

after in your packgage.json you need add the typings and files, add this lines

```json
      "typings": "types/index.d.ts",
      "files": ["types/*.d.ts"],
```

next, your warning disappear
[no warning types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkqUg.png)

this is the guide for solve warning

[DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/nuxtjs__auth)

Answer (score 14):

Edwin Rendoon Cadivid's answer works, but it's not the right way to do it.

I wrote the original typings and I just submitted another PR to bundle the typings with nuxt auth directly: https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/pull/486

<strike>After that PR is merged</strike>  as of `@nuxtjs/auth` v5 (which re-writes the module in typescript) all you will have to do is add `@nuxtjs/auth` to the `types` array in your tsconfig.json

```
    "types": [
      "@nuxt/types", 
      "@nuxtjs/auth" // Add this line
    ]
```

---

For now, until the PR is merged run
`npm install --save-dev @types/nuxtjs__auth`

Then add `@types/nuxtjs__auth` to you're `types` array in your `tsconfig.json`

```
    "types": [
      "@nuxt/types", 
      "@types/nuxtjs__auth" // Add this line
    ]
```

Comment: Eagerly waiting for merging the PR but no update yet :(

Comment: It was merged, just as part of a different PR now: <strike>https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/pull/486#issuecomment-616005542</strike>
Actually it's this one: https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/pull/621

Comment: merged but not yet released. So I resorted to this one. Thanks

Comment: I still get it when using in `middleware: (context)=>{context.$auth}`
Property '$auth' does not exist on type 'Context'

Comment: I still had to do option B

Answer (score 0):

`Nick Bolles`'s answer should work according to the docs, but I had to explicitly add the `$auth` property to `Vue`:

`types/vue-shim.d.ts`

```
import { Auth } from 'nuxtjs__auth'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    // ...
    readonly $auth: Auth
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a new major version of `@nuxtjs/auth`, the way to do it is well [documented here](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup).

## [Installation](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup#installation)

`npm install --save-exact @nuxtjs/auth-next`

Then, add `@nuxtjs/auth-next` to the modules section of `nuxt.config.js`:

```
{
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
  ],
  auth: {
    // Options
  }
}
```

## [Using with TypeScript](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup#using-with-typescript)

Then in your `tsconfig.json` add `@nuxtjs/auth-next` to the `compilerOptions.types` section :

```
{
  compilerOptions: {
    "types": [
      "@nuxtjs/auth-next",
    ]
  },
}
```

## Versions

Please check [this thread](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/status) to check status of versions.